# How to pass value from button ID to input on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I pass the ID of a button to a hidden input?

I have a foreach to list users and generate a delete button, I want to pass the button's ID to a hidden input inside a modal.

```
@foreach

<button type="button" id="{{$user->id}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-delete" onclick="deleteUser();"> Delete </button>

@endforeach
```

Here is what I've tried but didn't work.

```
function deleteUser(id) {
  $('input[name=user_id_modal]').val(id);

  alert(id);
}
```

`<input type="hidden" name="user_id_modal">
                            ^ button's id should go here.`

Comment: `onclick="deleteUser(this.id);"` passes the id to the function...

Comment: It seems there is a set of buttons & inputs. could you please demonstrate how they are positioned relating each other? I'm afraid we have not sufficient data to solve it. cause every input's name is not `user_id_modal` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the userId into the function and manipulate the hidden input's name value as follows:

```js
function deleteUser(id) {

  $("input[name='user_id_modal']").val(id);
  console.log("Input value set to: " + $("input[name='user_id_modal']").val());
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="userId" onclick="deleteUser(this.id);"> Delete </button>

<input type="hidden" name="user_id_modal">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @foreach

       <button type="button" id="{{$user->id}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-delete" onclick="deleteUser({{$user->id}});"> Delete </button>

   @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

<input id="button" type="button" value="Login" onclick="if (document.getElementById('password').value == 'PASSWORD') {

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).